# How do I effectively use the Tranquilizer Rifle on Deus Ex HR?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm totally badass and stealthy, but this gun is an exercise in frustration to use. I don't know if I am doing something wrong...

The gun has no crosshair. This makes it impossible to aim. I end up reloading my save about 10 times because I miss my target, and this is supposed to be 'A silent, long-ranged, precision weapon that fires tranquilizer darts to effortlessly subdue targets without permanent injury.'

I have some kind of addon where I am supposed to hold e, which activates something, but try as I might it seems to make no difference at all to anything, still no crosshair appears and it's as dreadful as before.

I was hoping to be able to snipe people with it, but it has an effective range of about 2 feet, so it's only used if I can't be bothered to step forward and punch someone, or to take down two people at once.

Please tell me I'm missing something? I'm about half way through the game but this has been bugging me since the start.

Comment: It has a sniper scope - use the middle button.

Comment: Might pay to go through the list of key bindings in Options before posting here :).

Comment: Might help if it told me there was a scope option to go looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the platform you're playing on in the question or in tags, but from your comment about holding 'e' I'm assuming you're playing on PC?

You should be able to look down the sights or scope of a weapon using the middle mouse button or by pressing the right shift key.

A full list of controls is available [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution/Controls).

Comment: also, having the target seeking system for long range shots helps a lot since it tells you how much to compensate for dart flight time

Comment: Oh my god you're kidding, you can scope!?!?!?!?!? The game really should have told me this!!!

Comment: Is it possible to change zoom level of the scope? I am having problems with finding my targets after I zoom in because it zooms way too much, thus restricting my view. (PS4 here)